# Blog integration into an existing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, rubygems, blogs

Are there any engines out there that would allow one to integrate a blog into an existing application/platform?

I'm quite new to rails but I am picking it up fairly quickly, and have implemented Devise, and Omniauth already, idealy I would like to have a blog implemented when a user logs in.

I've searched Stackoverflow, GitHub and other sources to no avail. However, I've heard Tom-Preston-Warner's Jekyll might work as a blog engine.

So my question is: Are there any gems, or tutorials that may help Rail's users implement blog engines into existing apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll uses git and files in a repo to build a blog, it's called a static site generator.  If you want a rails engine, take a look at `https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit`

Comment: Awesome, thanks @hwatkins -I'm thinking about using KatanaCodes blogit as the blog engine of choice for my application. Do you have previous experience with installing the engine? I am a little skeptical with the instructions provided on they're git as they aren't really as concise as I'd like.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment - The README needs a bit of work but the code is really well tested and is running great on three of our sites :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular blog engines out there is Refinery (https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog).  You can add the gem to your project and use it for your purposes.

It depends though how complex you want your blog.  It's quite easy to throw together something using just a dedicated controller and a few views.